# include sign when double-clicking numbers

Tags: c++, windows, mouseclick-event, textbox

I am working on a c++ project on windows 7 64-bit. I have a textbox field of type EDITTEXT on my GUI that stores numbers.

Currently every time I double click on it, the numbers are selected but not their signs. I would like to include the sign as well when I double click on it.

Are there any ways I can solve this problem? Is it a configuration problem on windows, or I need to implement a separate event handler (which I currently don't know how) in my project?

Comment: What type of signs are you working with?  You may have to escape them

Comment: Right now my textbox only contains positive and negative numbers, so I only need to capture the negative sign ('-')

Comment: I can't make a definite answer without looking at your code, but if you store the string representation of the number you should get the negative sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution but a work around for my problem.

I found out my project uses dialog-based windows to handle input data.

From that I can create a static control as a *LABEL* for my edittext control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997560.aspx) with SS_NOTIFY style (to capture mouse click messages) right before my edittext control.

Then in my custom DialogProc function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469(v=vs.85).aspx) I can handle what will happen if the user click/double click the *LABEL* of my edittext. For my case, I use EM_SETSEL message (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661(v=vs.85).aspx) to select everything in the edittext control

Because I cannot figure out how to capture messages sent when user clicking inside an edittext control, I have to implement it on the *LABEL* instead. This does not solve the root of the problem but at least it works  and its not a bad work around.